# xcodeでValidateした際のエラーについて

Tags: ios, xcode

> iTunes store operation failed
>   This action could not be completed. Try again.

というエラーが出てしまいます。
解決策を教えていただけますでしょうか。

こちらのサイトを参考にして作業を行っています。  
https://akira-watson.com/iphone/app-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

同じエラーでUploadできませんでしたが、
リリース用のipaをExportしてから
ApplicationLoader(v3.4)を使用してアップロードを行うとうまくいきました。

参考になれば。